# UV mapping issue when texture size is changed

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm developing an application for editing minecraft models. I'm using ThreeJS for displaying drawn texture mapped on the 3D player model, but there's an issue related to texture size change.

So, initially I have a texture mapped on the model like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOU2L.png), and when I change the texture height to 64, it becomes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jEDh.png).

I create texture like this:

```
/* Texture */
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);

texture.minFilter = texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
```

Where `canvas` is HTMLCanvasElement, and when the canvas' content is changed, I refresh the texture like that:

```
this.skin.render(canvas.getContext("2d"), this.skin.w, this.skin.h);

this.limbs.forEach(function (limb) {
    limb.mapUV(self.skin.w, self.skin.h);
});

this.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
this.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Where `this.material` is double sided transparent material with attached texture above. The UV's are appear to be correct.

I fixed similar problem in my previous application by recreating the whole mesh, but for this case it seems like it's going to be expensive.

How do I fix that? It's seems like the texture being cached or something, if I'm right, how can I uncache it?

Thank you for attention!

P.S.: Sorry for pictures. Due to my reputation, I can't post images yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent several hours tweaking my code to get the desired result, and in the end, I finally could solve my problem. The problem was that UV array elements of `geometry.faceVertexUvs` were cached somewhere in the core of ThreeJS.

My previous code of UV mapping was assigning the array of `Vector2` directly to `geometry.faceVertexUvs`:

```
geo.faceVertexUvs[0][side] = [faces[1], faces[2], faces[0]];
```

First time it works, but next times it gets cached, even though I'm marking UVs dirty (`geo.uvsNeedUpdate = true`), so instead of assigning the array, I end up with copying `Vector2` from `faces` array to each triangle vertex in `geo.faceVertexUvs[0][side]`:

```
geo.faceVertexUvs[0][side][0].copy(faces[1]);
geo.faceVertexUvs[0][side][1].copy(faces[2]);
geo.faceVertexUvs[0][side][2].copy(faces[0]);
```

I wish this (how to map UVs properly) was explained in the documentation of ThreeJS.